# Is There A Way To Use The Axes Input From A Joystick To Rotate A GameObject Around A Point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gun and a player (cube) on a 2d Unity Project. I have made a script that rotates the gun around the player depending on the position of the mouse on the screen. I was wondering if I could adapt this script to make the gun rotate depending on the Horizontal and Vertical values of a joystick?
this is what I have so far (don't worry about my terrible spelling):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponAming : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject bullet;
    public GameObject spawn;
    public ParticleSystem mf1;
    public ParticleSystem mf2;
    public float speed = .5f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        turning();
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("XButton"))
        {
            shoot();
        }
    }

    void turning()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = 10;
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

        Vector2 direc = new Vector2(mousePos.x - transform.position.x, mousePos.y - transform.position.y);

        transform.right = direc;
    }

    void shoot()
    {
        mf1.Play();
        mf2.Play();
        GameObject projectile = (GameObject)Instantiate(bullet, spawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        projectile.transform.right = transform.right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a direction from `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` and `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` if at least one is nonzero, and then set the transform's `right` to that direction:

```
void turning()
{
    float horiz = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vert = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if (horiz != 0 || vert != 0)
    {
        Vector2 direc = new Vector2(horiz, vert);

        transform.right = direc;
    }
}
```

If you would like to invert the controls vertically, negate `vert`:

```
void turning()
{
    float horiz = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vert = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if (horiz != 0 || vert != 0)
    {
        Vector2 direc = new Vector2(horiz, -vert);

        transform.right = direc;
    }
}
```

Comment: That Works! Although, when I move the joystick up it rotates down and vice versa.

Comment: Is There A Way To Make The Up Inputs Down And The Down Inputs Up?

Comment: nevermind! got it :D I just put a - sign in front of vert:

Comment: `void turning()
{
    float horiz = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vert = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if (horiz != 0 || vert != 0)
    {
        Vector2 direc = new Vector2(horiz, -vert);

        transform.right = direc;
    }
}`